# Как вычленить нужную информацию с переменной длиной из сплошной строки SQL

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

Помогите с вопросом:
есть база данных с такими данными:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

в строке подряд зашиты данные, которые мне нужны
XWID - личный номер, XDEV - витрина, XZON- зона, XPHN - телефон, три следующие цифры после этих слов - количество символов с данными этих атрибутов.
Должно получиться так:

| XWID | XDEV | XZON | XPHN |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 9998887766 | mmm | 8 | 9998887766 |
| 999988877766 | pppp | 4 | 9097976655 |

Проблема в том, что количество символов у этих атрибутов разное и они встречаются в разном порядке.
Работаю в PLSQL Devepoper

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Comment: Изменила вид. Надеюсь стало понятнее

Comment: Сейчас нет под рукой девелопера (. Попробуйте создать функцию, которая принимает код(XWID, XDEV..) и саму строку. Далее в строке ищете с помощью функции INSTR индекс вхождения. К нему прибавляете длину XDEV и берете 3 знака, преобразовывая к числу to_number, далее от найденного индекса + длина XDEV извлекаете значение с помощью substr() длиной полученного to_number. Будет универсальная функция для получения данных

Comment: Я пока новичок в этом всем. Но попробую разобраться. Спасибо

Comment: Какую версию Oracle вы используете?
`SELECT * FROM v$version;`

Comment: Когда задаете вопрос, необходимо предоставить "Минимальный воспроизводимый пример".
Для справки: [Как создать минимальный, самодостаточный и воспроизводимый пример](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Для вашего сценария это означает следующее:
(1) DDL и образец вставки данных, т.е. CREATE table(s) плюс операторы INSERT, в SQL.
(2) Что вам нужно сделать, т.е. логика и ваш SQL код пытающийся ее реализовать.
(3) Ожидаемый результат на основе примера данных в #1 выше.
(4) Ваша база данных (СУБД) и ее версия.
Все в рамках вопроса как текст, без картинок.

Answer (score 1):

Предложу вот такой вариант поиска нужных данных в строке по заданному ключу

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION GETDATA(
  FKEY VARCHAR2,
  FSTRING VARCHAR2
) return varchar2
IS
  pos number;
  poslen number;
  searchlen number;
  result varchar2;
BEGIN
  -- Получаем индекс начало подстроки заданного ключа
  select INSTR(FSTRING, FKEY) INTO pos from dual; 
  -- Получаем длину ключа
  select LENGHT(FKEY) INTO poslen from DUAL;
  -- Получаем длину нужной нам строки
  select to_number(substr(FSTRING, pos + poslen, 3)) into searchlen from dual;
  -- Выдергиваем нужную нам строку
  select substr(FSTRING, pos + poslen + 3, searchlen) into result from dual;
  -- Возвращаем результат
  return result;
END;
-- ====== Делаем выборку ======
select 
    GETDATA('XWID', t.field) XWID
  , GETDATA('XDEV', t.field) XDEV
  , GETDATA('XZON', t.field) XZON
  , GETDATA('XPHN', t.field) XPHN
from mySomeTable t;
```

Для того, что бы функцию можно было использовать в select запросах, она должна быть создана в схеме(Не в процедуре).

P.S. Так как проверить на текущий момент негде, могут быть ошибки, надо подтюнить.
Однако, как вариант решения, должно подойти

Comment: Большое спасибо!

Comment: Если, вдруг, решение подойдет, отметьте ответ как принятый. На этом сайте это больше чем спасибо. За хороший ответ можно так же проголосовать.

Comment: Хорошо, правда смогу проверить только в понедельник.

Comment: @Оксана А в понедельник я как раз смогу отладить ))

Comment: Отлично) Спасибо

Answer (score 1):

Если вы используете Oracle 18c или более позднюю версию.

Ваши данные очень похожи на JSON. Итак, будем составлять JSON.

После этого все легко.

Последовательный порядок токенов не имеет значения.

Если вам нужны значения, начиная с 4-й позиции, вы можете использовать для этого функцию `SUBSTR(json_value(j, '$.XWID'), 4)` и так далее.

[SQL Fiddle](https://sqlize.online/sql/oracle19/ce822fed35fcca032d1af6f85035cfc5/)

**SQL**

```
CREATE TABLE tbl (ID int, fld_126 VARCHAR2(100) NOT NULL);
 
INSERT INTO tbl (ID, fld_126) 
WITH rs AS ( 
    SELECT 1, 'XWID9998887766XDEVmmmXZON8XPHN9998887766'      FROM dual UNION ALL 
    SELECT 2, 'XDEVppppXWID999988877766XZON4XPHN9097976655'   FROM dual 
)
SELECT * FROM rs;

SELECT ID, j
    , json_value(j, '$.XWID') as XWID -- SUBSTR(json_value(j, '$.XWID'), 4)
    , json_value(j, '$.XDEV') as XDEV
    , json_value(j, '$.XZON') as XZON
    , json_value(j, '$.XPHN') as XDEV
FROM tbl t
CROSS APPLY (
   SELECT treat(REPLACE('{' || REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(fld_126
        ,'XWID','","XWID":"')
        ,'XDEV','","XDEV":"')
        ,'XZON','","XZON":"')
        ,'XPHN','","XPHN":"')
        , '{",','{') || '"}' as json)  As j FROM dual
) CrossApplied;
```

**Результат**

```
| ID | J                                                                    | XWID         | XDEV | XZON | XPHN       |
|----|----------------------------------------------------------------------|--------------|------|------|------------|
| 1  | {"XWID":"9998887766","XDEV":"mmm","XZON":"8","XPHN":"9998887766"}    | 9998887766   | mmm  | 8    | 9998887766 |
| 2  | {"XDEV":"pppp","XWID":"999988877766","XZON":"4","XPHN":"9097976655"} | 999988877766 | pppp | 4    | 9097976655 |
```

Comment: Спасибо. В понедельник узнаю версию и попробую

Comment: `XWID` может быть не первым среди перечисленных полей

Comment: @ESkri, спасибо, поправил.

Comment: А если строка `XWID` случайно встретится среди данных где-то в этой строке?

Comment: @Оксана, Была ли у вас возможность попробовать предложенное решение?